# Spark submit ,how to read user input parameters?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

Need to pass additional input parameter to spark job to validate . I know that after uber.jar we can pass all required parameters by giving space. Have option to read like below parameter using scala

```
spark-submit --jar uber.jar -Dtable.name=emp -Dfiltercondition=age,name
```

Comment: This could be helpful, I used it some time ago https://github.com/scopt/scopt

Answer (score 2):

`-D` format is mostly for Java properties, not CLI arguments.

Spark accepts arguments through your app main method like any other Java/Scala program.

```
object App {

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cmd: CommandLine = parseArg(args) // <-- here
    val master = cmd.getOptionValue("master", "local[*]") // parse args

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName(App.getClass.getName)
      .master(master)
      .getOrCreate()
    ...
  }

  // Using Apache Commons CLI
  private def parseArg(args: Array[String]): CommandLine = {
    import org.apache.commons.cli._

    val options = new Options

    ...
  }
```

Then `spark-submit --jar app.jar --className=my.app.App --master='local[*]'`